# navbar на бутсрапе не сворачивается

Tags: bootstrap, navigationbar

Бутстраповская навигация некорректно работает. В мобильной версии когда список(пункты) меню должны сворачиваться - этого не происходит. Сворачивается только фон меню. Сам маркированный список остается неподвижным. Как это исправить и как сделать чтобы по умолчанию меню было свёрнуто?
Вот код

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#responsive-menu">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="responsive-menu">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт 5</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#responsive-menu">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="responsive-menu">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Пункт 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Пункт 5</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Я подключил все, и сделал тут, запусти,  посмотри, работает все ок...

Comment: нет, с этим всё впорядке, проверил

Comment: Тогда ожидайте других людей со стажем)
Только что запустил этот код у себя, все ок.

Comment: Не сворачивается сам маркированный список, а меню(бекграунд) сворачиваеться и разворачиваеться(как раз под высоту списка) без проблем, Может класс какой то пропущен или другой атрибут?

Comment: я использую сборщик grunt может в этом дело?

Comment: С ним не работал , по этому не скажу этого. Опыта за спиной огромного не достиг.

Comment: @Bohdan Запусти и посмотри , я изменил немного свой ответ

Comment: Не работает.По прежнему сворачивается только фон. Скорее всего дело в grunt. Но спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @Bohdan Был бы рад получить "Ответ полезен"(стрелочка вверх) с вашей стороны.

Comment: репутация не позволяет. свежий аккаунт